# Opencv GPU enabled cards

Tags: opencv, image-processing, cuda, nvidia, ati

Iam using Opencv 2.4.3 , my grpahic card is ATI , but I keep reading that CUDA is Nvidia enabaled , does this mean I can't use gpu functions as long as I have ATI graphic card ?

Comment: you probably want ocl, then, not cuda.

Comment: ocl ? pcl you mean ? point cloud library ?

Comment: ooh googled, openCL ... will check this out , thanks

Comment: no, ocl, another way of gpu optimization ( not restricted to nvidia hardware )

Comment: also, do yourself a favour, and update to opencv2.4.7 ( all that gpu stuff seems to have been the major focus of the opencv devs lately )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, **CUDA Technology is exclusive to NVIDIA devices**, so ATI video cards doesn't support it.

**However**, [OpenCV 2.4.3](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) [was the](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2013/07/09/opencv-cl-computer-vision-with-opencl-acceleration/) [first version to support](http://opencv.org/opencv-2-4-3-released.html) [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). There has been a considerable amount of changes to the [ocl module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html) since it was first released, so I suggest you upgrade to a more recent version.

**You might be able to enjoy OpenCV's GPU processing if your [ATI video card supports OpenCL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/).**